# Hello to everyone. I just started learning html alone and i have a question

Tags: html

I made an html file and I would like to give it an http. In this site I want to upload content from my pc. Is it safe to do this and share the link to others so they can see my content? If not what should I do? Sorry if my english are not so good.

Answer (score 0):

yeah its safe but u also need a domain name and a web hosting wich both costs money, u can get some domain names for free and a free webhosting is 000webhost.com.
also a free domain hosting is vimexx.nl

if you have further questions let me know :D